# Unable to set multiple attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the HTML Code:

```js
$('#shadowfax').hover(function () {
  $('#horsename').attr({
    class: 'display-5',
    text: 'Ive been through the desert on a horse with no name. It felt good to be out of the rain. In the desert you can remember your name. Cause there aint no one for to give you no pain...'});
},
function () {
  $('#horsename').text('A Horse with no name');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm">
  <img id="shadowfax" src="images/horse.jpg" alt="ShadowFax">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg">
    <p class="display-4" id="horsename">A Horse with no name</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am unable to change the content of the horsename element based on hover on shadowfax element.

I am using jQuery v3.3.1 and Bootstrap v4.

Thanks

Comment: Check your function's syntax, I think there's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('#shadowfax').hover(function () {
  $('#horsename')
    .attr("class", 'display-5')
    .text('Ive been through the desert on a horse with no name. It felt good to be out of the rain. In the desert you can remember your name. Cause there aint no one for to give you no pain...');
}, function () {
  $('#horsename').text('A Horse with no name');
});
```

```css
.display-4 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.display-5 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm">
  <img id="shadowfax" src="images/horse.jpg" alt="ShadowFax">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg">
    <p class="display-4" id="horsename">A Horse with no name</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The way you are setting text, will only set a text attribute instead of changing the text.

`$('#horsename').text(UPDATED_TEXT)` will update the DOM text, whereas `$('#horsename').attr("text", UPDATED_TEXT)` will add a text attribute with **UPDATED_TEXT** value.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.text()` and `toggleClass()` OR (addClass / removeClass) methods on horsename element -

Note: There is end div tag with no start tag present in your posted html. Please verify it on your end.

```js
var $horsName = $('#horsename');
$('#shadowfax').hover(function () {
      $horsName.toggleClass('display-5');
      $horsName.text('Ive been through the desert on a horse with no name. It felt good to be out of the rain. In the desert you can remember your name. Cause there aint no one for to give you no pain...');
    },
    function () {
        $horsName.toggleClass('display-5');
        $horsName.text('A Horse with no name');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm">
   <img id="shadowfax" src="images/horse.jpg" alt="ShadowFax">
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg">
      <p class="display-4" id="horsename">A Horse with no name</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax issues in your code.

Code sample with the right solution:

```js
$('#shadowfax').hover(function () {
  $('#horsename')
    .attr("class", 'display-5')
    .text('Ive been through the desert on a horse with no name. It felt good to be out of the rain. In the desert you can remember your name. Cause there aint no one for to give you no pain...');
}, function () {
  $('#horsename').text('A Horse with no name');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm">
  <img id="shadowfax" src="images/horse.jpg" alt="ShadowFax">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg">
    <p class="display-4" id="horsename">A Horse with no name</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use events on HTML elements like this -

```
<div class="col-sm">
        <img id="shadowfax" onmouseover='onMouseHover()' src="images/horse.jpg" alt="ShadowFax">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg">
          <p class="display-4" onmouseout='onMouseOut()' id="horsename">A Horse with no name</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

<kbd>[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hqTfusx2XRVF1Ce55vnQ?p=preview)</kbd>